# How to change user.home for websphere liberty

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I am trying to create a liberty cluster. While generating the keys, liberty is creating some keys under logged-in user's home directory which is c:\users\xyz\ .ssh.

How do I say liberty to save the keys under d:\users\xyz\ .ssh?

I need this because, i am working in citrix environment and c drive image is always replaced upon restart and I am loosing the keys forcing me to create the cluster again or save a copy of the keys before I log out for day.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try displaying options for registerHost action like this:

```
D:\Liberty\wlp\bin>collective.bat help registerHost
```

it shows `rpcUserHome` param, which might be what you are looking for:

```
--rpcUserHome=path
    Optional. The home directory for the user with which to authenticate
    to the RPC mechanism. Defaults to the current OS user home directory.
    This value is used when generating SSH keys.
```

Comment: I will give it a try. Thank you

Comment: I tried it with no luck. I did not see a authorized_keys file being created in the rpcUserHome location also i did not notice a ssh key being added into the existing user home authorized_keys file when I join the member.